# Having difficulties flattening JSON in Go

Tags: json, go, struct

I am trying to flatten the structs I will be working with and I can't seem to figure out how to get one working.

Here is a snippet of the JSON I have:

```json
{
    "vehicles": {
        "1": {
            "all": {
                "spotted": 123,
                "hits": 123
            }
        },
        "2": {
            "all": {
                "spotted": 123,
                "hits": 123
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After doing some googling I found a way to put it all into a struct with a map, but this will make it very hard to work with because I will need to check every `vehicle_id` like  Session[`vehicle_id`].Spotted. Is there a way to get rid of that map workaround and just have a flat struct?

This is how my struct looks right now:

```golang
type RetroSession struct {
    Vehicles        *map[string]VehicleStats        `json:"vehicles" bson:"vehicles"`
}
type VehicleStats struct {
    *StatsFrame             `json:"all" bson:"all"`
}
type StatsFrame struct {
    Spotted              int `json:"spotted" bson:"spotted"`
    Hits                 int `json:"hits" bson:"hits"`
}
```

I want to remove those `vehicle_id.all` keys for each vehicle and just make it something like this:

```golang
type Session struct {
   Vehicles     *[]Vehicle
}

type Vehicle struct {
    Spotted              int `json:"spotted" bson:"spotted"`
    Hits                 int `json:"hits" bson:"hits"`
}
```

Comment: Well, first of all, that snippet is invalid JSON

Comment: Why don't you just unmarshal it as you do and then just convert RetroSession struct into a Session struct for further usage?

Comment: How would I go about converting those structs properly? I tried a for loop, but I can't loop over `cannot range over data.Vehicles (type *map[string]externalapis.VehicleStats)`

Found the issue, I left it as pointer -_-

Is there a more efficient way to convert Structs in Go than just setting each field separately?

Comment: You can simplify the code to work with these types by changing map pointers to maps and slice pointers to slice.  Show the code that you tried so far.

Comment: Here is what I got so far https://gist.github.com/Cufee/68f5b6bf5b95e6fc9b7f17dc89425350. It is working fine, I just need a way to detect if a document is old or new format. I think I can do this with query tools available in Mongo. Yeah I was just playing around with pointers while working on this. Just starting with Go and testing stuff out :D

Comment: What @MuffinTop said - you probably don't want to have a pointer to a map and a pointer to a slice (although you maybe do want a slice of pointers?)

After that, you can have a simple function to convert between the types: https://play.golang.org/p/xiu2ef__iLq